# In Node.js is it possible to use parts of Connect with standard node HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I have a node.js app which I need to add more complexity to at this point. Connects middleware is perfect for what I want to do and cleaner than `if/else` logic BUT I don't want the level of abstraction Connect provides from a server perspective (I want very low level granular control over http headers and http response logic). So my question is can I use Connects middleware `next()` type functionality within a standard

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {}).listen(port)
```

type block?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I guess I was looking at this the wrong way. 
I can wrap my existing code inside a Connect server pretty easily and still use the http interface.  i.e.

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var app = connect()
app.use( function myMiddleWare(req, res, next ){

// my preexisting Node HTTP interface code. 
//obviously I can use modules to make this cleaner 

next();
});

var server = app.listen(port);
```